# Is it possible to suppress invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char* errors with a compiler flag when porting over to newer RHEL versions?

Tags: c++, compilation

I encounter the invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char* while compiling some code on a newer RHEL host.

The error I encounter comes from an external library that I'm including that ideally I'd not like to change and I'm aware that ideally the correct solution is to fix the error in the .h file in the external project which throws this error.

However, I was wondering if there's a compiler flag that I can pass in to ignore this error or convert it to a warning for a period of time until this error is fixed by the owner of the library?

Thank you

Comment: ~~Can you just wrap your const pointer in a `const_cast<char*>(ptr)`?~~ Sorry, missed that this was inside the library.  I usually run into these kind of problems at the interface boundary with old libs that aren't const-aware.

Comment: @RyanBemrose "from an external library that I'm including that ideally I'd not like to change"

Comment: Thanks Ryan, but I do not have permissions to change this external lib. Hence, the check to see if I can convert the error into a warning. The original library worked on an older RHEL version but the newer default compiler is stricter. Yep, Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a minimal complete example of code that used to be accepted, but is not accepted any longer? For C++ code, even GCC 3.3 rejects `char *f(const char *x) { return x; }`. The first release of the 3.3.x versions was in 2003.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider using `-isystem /path/to/your/libs/headers` to suppress all warnings from all include files in the given directory (unless you then use `-Wsystem-headers` to show them anyways).
And then you would use :

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-fpermissive"
#include <yourlibrary>
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

To turn that error into a warning, however this is a bit of a hack and may hide or introduce bugs.

The clean solution would be to *actually fix the warning* of course, but that doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: `-isystem` won't work by itself. Warnings are suppressed in system headers, but errors aren't. And the `-fno-permissive` option doesn't do what you think it does: it merely cancels an earlier `-fpermissive` option. It's `-fpermissive` that turns this particular error into a warning. (Which should then be suppressible using `-isystem`, as you noted.) However, it doesn't just hide bugs in code, it *introduces* bugs in code. It intentionally doesn't just accept non-standard C++, it also gives standard C++ code different meaning.

Comment: @hvd right, I was confused. However, -isystem should work if combined with `#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-fpermissive"`

Comment: Well. I'm not seeing any really good solution, outside of actually fixing the library. But here's a hack anyways. Maybe it'll be useful to you.